# Is there another streaming video tools?

Tags: python, streaming, video-streaming, dvblast

I like to stream a video in the internet,and I search to find some streaming tools to help me in this manner. I can find one open source   [dvblast](http://www.videolan.org/projects/dvblast.html)

Now, Is there another open source or paid tools can help me?

Is there any python package to do this?

**hint : I want to use It for stream video like TV shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

1)http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming

2)http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html

3)http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

that vlc use dvblast!

Comment: you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433597/streaming-audio-and-video?rq=1

Comment: another source : http://pythonhosted.org/python-librtmp/#

Comment: another one : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DeeFuzzer/